# Powerpoint OLE link reseting when changing in a different PC

Tags: excel, powerpoint, ole

I'm working on a PowerPoint project that I need other people to access and update many OLE links contained in the ppt that point to an excel file that the person should have on their computer.

The thing is when the person tries to change the OLE path to their path and update it, the path gets kind of reseted.

I.E.:

The path of one of the OLE links in my computer is:

```
"Myuser\Desktop\ProjectX\filename.xlsm!somesheet!L2C2:L2C3"
```

As soon as another person gets the ppt and changes the link in their computer, at first everything works well:

```
"AnotherPerson\Desktop\ProjectX\filename.xlsm!somesheet!L2C2:L2C3"
```

When they click "Update now" it doesn't work and the path gets resumed to:

```
"AnotherPerson\Desktop\ProjectX\filename.xlsm"
```

So it stops point to the part of the excel file it was supposed to.

Does anyone knows how to solve this or why does this happen?

It's also worth mentioning I've tried changing the path both manually and through VBA and the outputs are the same.

Comment: How were the links created? It's been my experience that if you start in PPT and do Insert | Object to create the link, it will fail in various ways. The more reliable way is to select the information first in a SAVED Excel worksheet, copy it, then Paste Special, as Excel chart or object, and choose to link.

Comment: That's exactly how it was done, copying the excel data and using Paste Special.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Are the recipients of the files using SharePoint or OneDrive? That seems to cause a lot of linking issues. If so, have them DL the files to their own drive to see if things work as expected there.  If you're emailing the files to them, have them save to their hdd as well rather than opening from within Outlook or other email app. And before opening any of the saved files in either case, have them right click, choose Properties and on the general tab, use the option to UNBLOCK the file, if it appears. For both of the files.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm already doing all of those things, haven't been using OneDrive or blocked files.

Comment: Just to clarify:  Blocking a file isn't something you or another user does. It's something that Microsoft does to any file that comes to you over the internet or (I think?) untrusted local networks. YOU may not have done anything to block the file but have you followed my suggestion to verify that the file's not blocked?  Sorry if this seems pedantic, but the answer's not obvious.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but yes, I've verifyied if the files are not blocked through their properties.

Comment: This is worth reporting to MS via Help | Send Feedback.  They DO look at these things. Meanwhile, a shot in the dark ... try creating a range that encompasses the section of the worksheet you want to link to, then copy/paste link to PPT.